# Finding a few records by id using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, travis-ci

I am trying to load a few favorite repositories for the Travis-CI Mobile I am trying to put together [here](https://github.com/floydpink/Travis-CI-www)

What I have is an array of repository IDs like this:

```
var favoriteRepos = ["668498","557554","7934","207993"];
```

How could we go about loading all these repos with the ember-data revision 12, [the Travis custom RESTAdapter](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web/blob/master/assets/scripts/app/store/rest_adapter.coffee) and the [Travis API](https://api.travis-ci.org/docs/)?

This is what I have tried unsuccessfully so far:

```
// This is in the repo model - https://github.com/floydpink/Travis-CI-www/blob/master/js/app/models/Repo.js
Repo.reopenClass({
  favorites     : function (favorites) {
    // favorites would be an array of repo-ids like  ["451069","538603"]
    var faves = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
      isLoadedBinding : 'content.isLoaded',
      content         : Ember.A([])
    });
    favorites.forEach(function (favorite) {
      faves.pushObject(Repo.find(favorite));
    });
    return faves;
  }
});

// And in FavoritesController
this.set('content', Repo.favorites(favoriteRepos));
```

So the generic question is, how do we go about loading a few different records by id, using ember-data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```js
Repo.reopenClass({
  favorites     : function (favorites) {
    // favorites would be an array of repo-ids like  ["451069","538603"]
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins({
      content: favorites.map(function(id) { return Repo.find(id); }),
      isLoaded: function() {
        return this.everyProperty('isLoaded');
      }.property('@each.isLoaded');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's something else within my setup, but this is not working. Although, if I just do `return Repo.find()` it does work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not working". If `Repo.find` works, this will work too. Of course, you have to remember that the objects won't be populated immediately. If you haven't set things up correctly to deal with this elsewhere that could be your problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `isLoaded` support. I'm pretty sure the code should work though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you. Needed to first extend and then create the ArrayProxy, because of an error: `Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties`. [Working version](https://github.com/floydpink/Travis-CI-www/commit/60ae6a35ce87fe9785302f1d7ed36b993a156499#diff-0).

Comment: Looks like your adapter cool look into supporting `findMany`.

Comment: @rpflo: I am using the exact same store, adapter, serializer and base model as the [official travis client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web). And since the adapter there is extending [ember-data RESTAdapter](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web/blob/master/assets/scripts/app/store/rest_adapter.coffee#L63), it could probably be already there. I will give that a try as well. Thanks

Comment: @rpflo, good point about the findMany endpoint. I don't think ember-data currently exposes it, but it is used internally for relationships and maybe could be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

If your handlebars template looks like this:

```
{{#if isLoaded}}
  {{#each controller}}
    ...
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Then it won't work because you never set `isLoaded` to `true` on your array. Depending on which data implementation you use, you could do something like this:

```
Repo.reopenClass({
  favorites: function (ids) {
    // ids would be an array of repo-ids like  ["451069","538603"]
    var loadCount = 0;
    var favorites = Em.A();
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      var favorite = Repo.find(id);
      favorites.pushObject(favorite);
      favorites.then(function() {
        loadCount++;
        if (loadCount == ids.length) {
          favorites.set('isLoaded', true);
        }
      });
    });
    return favorites;
  }
});
```

The `isLoaded` property is set to true once all favorites have been loaded from the server.

Comment: Getting an error `Object [object Object] has no method 'then'` at the `favorites.then()` line.